# Vim: Delete the text matching a pattern IF submatch(1) is empty

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

This command line parses a contact list document that may or may not have either a phone, email or web listed.  If it has all three then everything works great - appending the return from the FormatContact() at the end of the line for data uploading:

```
silent!/^\d/+1|ki|/\n^\d\|\%$/-1|kj|'i,'jd|let @a = substitute(@",'\s*Phone: \([^,]*\)\_.*','\1',"")|let @b = substitute(@",'^\_.*E-mail:\s\[\d*\]\([-_@.0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\_.*','\1',"")|let @c = substitute(@",'^\_.*Web site:\s*\[\d*\]\([-_.:/0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\_.*','\1',"")|?^\d\+?s/$/\=','.FormatContact(@a,@b,@c)
```

or, broken down:

```
silent!/^\d/+1|ki|/\n^\d\|\%$/-1|kj|'i,'jd
let @a = substitute(@",'\s*Phone: \([^,]*\)\_.*','\1',"")
let @b = substitute(@",'^\_.*E-mail:\s\[\d*\]\([-_@.0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\_.*','\1',"")
let @c = substitute(@",'^\_.*Web site:\s*\[\d*\]\([-_.:/0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\_.*','\1',"")
?^\d\+?s/$/\=','.FormatContact(@a,@b,@c)
```

I created three separate searches so as not to make any ONE search fail if one atom failed to match because - again - the contact info may or may not exist per contact.

**The Problem** that solution created was that when the pattern does not match I get the whole @" into @a. Instead, I need it to be empty when the match does not occur. I need each variable represented (phone,email,web) whether it be empty or not.

1. I see no flags that can be set in the substitution function that
   will do this.
2. Is there a way to return "" if \1 is empty?
3. Is there a way to create an optional atom so the search query(ies) could still account for an empty match so as to properly record it as empty?

Comment: can you make it a bit clearer what you are trying to do? Are you processing input linewise? Who yanks the selection in the first place? Where is @a going to be used. (_I tried my best getting something succinct out of this, but short of writing a vimscript function nothing worked well for me_)

Comment: @sehe the post has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using substitutions that replace the whole captured text
with its part of interest, one can match only that target part. Unlike
substitution routines, matching ones either locate the text conforming
to the given pattern, or report that there is no such text. Thus,
using the `matchstr()` function in preference to `substitute()`, the
parsing code listed in the question can be changed as follows:

```
let @a = matchstr(@", '\<Phone:\s*\zs[^,]*')
let @b = matchstr(@", '\<E-mail:\s*\[\d*\]\zs[-_@.0-9a-zA-Z]*')
let @c = matchstr(@", '\<Web site:\s*\[\d*\]\zs[-_.:/0-9a-zA-Z]*')
```

Comment: Guru @ib. You are AMAZING!  :)  I actually solved this using another technique I learned from you (the "!=" matching for words in the "FormatContact" function), but I knew there was a better way - I implemented your above post.  I think I read about matchstr in the vim help, but it's just too much to remember it all.  Thank you so much (again).

Comment: Guru @ib. you've been an exceptional help to me.  I'm coming back for more!  :)  Can you look at this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887207/screen-scraping-automating-a-vim-script Thank you!

Comment: I got your email.  Thanks for chasing me down!  Responding privately.  You should have gotten an email from me from my gmail account as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want linewise processing, consider using in combination with :global, e.g.

```
let @a=""
g/text to match/let @A=substitute(getline("."), '^.*\(' . @/ . '\).*$', '\1\r', '')
```

This will print the matched text for any line that contained it, separated with newlines:

```
echo @a
```

The beautiful thing here, is that you can make it work with the last-used *search-pattern* very easily:

```
g//let @A=substitute(getline("."), '^.*\(' . @/ . '\).*$', '\1\r', '')
```

Comment: Thanks @sehe this is creative thinking and I'll keep it mind.  I reposted the OP per your request to make it clearer.  Please take another look.  Thank you!